# Looking for a way to append data from a div to a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Complete nubie here and perhaps I do not know enough about how a CSS website works but I am looking to do something I think should be fairly simple. …and I hate to think I am the only one who is trying to do this.
I am working with an automatically generated css / java script website. On the “individual” page it lists a person’s name in one of the header tags (h2 if you need to know) I would like to capture the name and add it to a variable in a script that I found that will basically append it to a url and present the url as a hyperlink called “View All Media”. I am using the url to search a database page. Here’s the script I am using:

```
<html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var scrt_var =  ;
openPage = function() {location.href = "http://my.website.net/all_media.asp?tags="+scrt_var;}
</script>
<a href ="javascript:openPage()">View All Media </a>
</html>
```

On the “individual page” the tag I am trying to get the text from is `<h2 id='name'></h2>` which is the person’s name. The database is based on the person’s name so in a nutshell all I want to do is take the name off the page and append it to the hyperlink as a search parameter. Here is where the name gets put on the page and I would imagine it gets the data from one of the scripts that are listed at the top of the page:

```
`<div id='content'>`
`<h1>Individual Details</h1>` 
`<h2 id='name'></h2>`
```

If I put the person’s name in the script manually in the “var scrt_var =  ;” line (like var scrt_var = “John Doe” ;) it works. All I am trying to do is get the nane from the page (or source wherever it is) and put it in the "var=" line automatically. I think it should be a fairly simple task but I have been all over the net and all I can find are scripts that will change the tags or add hyperlinks to them...not get he data. I want to do it the other way around…sort of. I have some familiarity with scripts but really at a complete loss on how to do this. Any thoughts would be very much appreciated?....oh and please be gentle - Thanks! 

Comment: you want to get the data from a page that is not the current page and not loaded yet ?

Comment: Its the data on the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var scrt_var = document.getElementById('name').textContent;
```

You'll need to make sure that the document has loaded before you make that assignment, or do it in your function.

```
openPage = function() {
    location.href = "http://my.website.net/all_media.asp?tags="+document.getElementById('name').textContent;
}
```

Comment: It would be better practice to use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) instead of `.innerHTML` because it works if there are elements inside the `<h2>` and it mitigates the risk of [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks if users have control over the name.

Comment: Works Great!! And thanks you so much for the quick answer! Unfortunately for me, there is a whole lot more imbedded in this header the just the person’s name. If I plug in any of the other tags on the page I get exactly what is displayed on the page. Soooo again, the code works great, it just looks like I need to do a little more “tweaking” to filter out the unnecessary stuff. Thanks again for your time and expertise!